# Is there any way to disable grouping databases in phpMyAdmin?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

If you have db names like

```
test_db1
test_db2
```

phpmyadmin would create a group `test`. The group appears in the left side-bar with related databases displayed under it.

How can I disable this feature?

Comment: You don't like it?

Comment: @Khaled: not really

Answer (score 33, accepted):

I know this is something old -- so I'm posting here just in case someone stumbles in the same question.

In the latest versions of phpMyAdmin the setting to flip is NavigationTreeEnableGrouping, i.e. in **config.inc.php** set:

```
$cfg['NavigationTreeEnableGrouping'] = false;
```

p.s. on localhost, **config.inc.php** is placed in /phpmyadminX.XX/ folder

Or, for a "current session only", you can do it from phpmyadmin STARTPAGE: click settings -> navigation panel -> uncheck "group items in tree"

Comment: Worth noting, that this is system-wide setting (not per server), so you should set it as `$cfg['NavigationTreeEnableGrouping']` in the end of configuration file. Not, as `$cfg['Servers'][$i]['NavigationTreeEnableGrouping']` (in the beginning of config).

Comment: Saved my life with this. It was driving me insane.

Answer (score 5):

You can disable grouping by setting `LeftFrameDBTree` to false:

```
$cfg['LeftFrameDBTree'] = false;
```

UPDATE: the option was [renamed](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/history/blob/master/ChangeLogs/ChangeLog-2013) to `NavigationTreeEnableGrouping` in phpMyAdmin 4.0.0.0 (2013-05-03).

Answer (score 0):

(can't comment yet #*@%!)

It seems relevant to precise that dependind on your linux distro, config file locations may vary.

On my Debian (squeeze),  /usr/share/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php  contains a warning on the first lines, which I might well have missed :

```
/**
 * Please, do not edit this file. The configuration file for Debian
 * is located in the /etc/phpmyadmin directory.
 */
```

I have no idea whether this file may be replaced by some update or other mechanism, but it is usually a good practice to do things the way they are supposed to be.

I also wanted to add that [eugene y](https://serverfault.com/users/34662/eugene-y)'s answer saved me, but could have been more accurate :

The exact parameter name, and what I have to set, on my probably old version of phpmyadmin, is

```
$cfg['LeftFrameDBTree'] = false;
```

Btw, his link is kinda dead, which is the reason why answer are better copied here.

And @[adriano72](https://serverfault.com/users/147123/adriano72), whose response is probably more up to date, I'd like to ask a precision about what are "the latest versions".  As of which year ?

I'm *not even sure* thoses version are more recent than the ones of [eugene y](https://serverfault.com/users/34662/eugene-y)'s answer.  I guess so, because of post dates, and could of course check, but my point is that those points should be clarified.

If you think my comments are useful, please, upvote this, so that next time, I can comment where it belongs.